# Working with substr_count() and arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, substring

So what I need is to compare a string to an array *(string as a haystack and array as a needle)* and get the elements from the string that repeat within the array. For this purpose I've taken a sample function for using an array as a needle in the `substr_count` function.

```
$animals = array('cat','dog','bird');
$toString = implode(' ', $animals);
$data = array('a');

function substr_count_array($haystack, $needle){
     $initial = 0;
     foreach ($needle as $substring) {
          $initial += substr_count($haystack, $substring);
     }
     return $initial;
}

echo substr_count_array($toString, $data);
```

The problem is that if I search for a character such as *'a'*, it gets through the check and validates as a legit value because *'a'* is contained within the first element. So the above outputs `1`. I figured this was due to the `foreach()` but how do I bypass that? I want to search for a whole string match, not partial.

Comment: I need to match the whole word as an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break up the `$haystack` into individual words, then do an `in_array()` check over it to make sure the word exists in that array as a whole word before doing your `substr_count()`:

```
$animals = array('cat','dog','bird', 'cat', 'dog', 'bird', 'bird', 'hello');
$toString = implode(' ', $animals);
$data = array('cat');

function substr_count_array($haystack, $needle){
    $initial = 0;
    $bits_of_haystack = explode(' ', $haystack);
    foreach ($needle as $substring) {
        if(!in_array($substring, $bits_of_haystack))
            continue; // skip this needle if it doesn't exist as a whole word

        $initial += substr_count($haystack, $substring);
    }
    return $initial;
}

echo substr_count_array($toString, $data);
```

[Here, `cat` is 2, `dog` is 2, `bird` is 3, `hello` is 1 and `lion` is 0.](https://eval.in/173527)

---

**Edit:** here's another alternative using [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) with the search parameter set to the `$needle`:

```
function substr_count_array($haystack, $needle){
    $bits_of_haystack = explode(' ', $haystack);
    return count(array_keys($bits_of_haystack, $needle[0]));
}
```

Of course, this approach requires a string as the needle. I'm not 100% sure why you need to use an array as the needle, but perhaps you could do a loop outside the function and call it for each needle if you need to - just another option anyway!

Comment: Yes, that solves it. Thanks for the time allocated. Will accept the answer as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just throwing my solution in the ring here; the basic idea, as outlined by scrowler as well, is to break up the search subject into separate words so that you can compare whole words.

```
function substr_count_array($haystack, $needle) 
{
    $substrings = explode(' ', $haystack);

    return array_reduce($substrings, function($total, $current) use ($needle) {
        return $total + count(array_keys($needle, $current, true));
    }, 0);
}
```

The `array_reduce()` step is basically this:

```
$total = 0;
foreach ($substrings as $substring) {
    $total = $total + count(array_keys($needle, $substring, true));
}
return $total;
```

The `array_keys()` expression returns the keys of `$needle` for which the value equals `$substring`. The size of that array is the number of occurrences.